# regex match in body tag: then add class to all elements containing the matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

This is my body:

```
<div>http://www.example.com</div>
<span>http://www.mywebsite.com</span><br>
<b>http://www.domain.com</b>
```

This is my simple regex (works):

```
document.body.innerHTML.match(/(http|https|ftp):\/\/(?:www\.)?([a-z]|\d|-)+\.(?:([a-z]|-)+\.)*?(com|net|org)(?:\/)?/ig);
```

How can I add a class to all elements that contain the matches in javascript or jquery? Example:

```
<div class="matchClass">http://www.example.com</div>
<span class="matchClass">http://www.mywebsite.com</span><br>
<b class="matchClass">http://www.domain.com</b>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cz6owdxx/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cz6owdxx/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny with your code also the body receives that class...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cz6owdxx/4/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like

```
$('body').children()
    .filter(function () {
    return this.innerHTML.match(/(http|https|ftp):\/\/(?:www\.)?([a-z]|\d|-)+\.(?:([a-z]|-)+\.)*?(com|net|org)(?:\/)?/ig);
}).addClass('matchClass');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz6owdxx/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$.each(myMatch, function(k, v) {
    $("body *:contains(" + v + ")").addClass("matchClass")
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/cz6owdxx/3/

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
/<(.+)>((http|https|ftp):\/\/(?:www\.)?([a-z]|\d|-)+\.(?:([a-z]|-)+\.)*?(com|net|org)(?:\/)?)<\/(.+)>/ig
```

And replace with

```
<$1 class="matchClass">$2<$7>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cz6owdxx/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
(>(http|https|ftp):\/\/(?:www\.)?([a-z]|\d|-)+\.(?:([a-z]|-)+\.)*?(com|net|org)(?:\/)?)
```

You can try this.Repalce by `class="matchClass"$1`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/16